# Is $H_{m}$ a measurable set?

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

Let $\mathbb{R}^{4}$ be equipped with its usual Euclidean topology and associated Borel $\sigma$-algebra. If $x = (x_{0},x_{1},x_{2},x_{3}) \in \mathbb{R}^{4}$, define $\tilde{x}$ by $(x_{0},-x_{1},-x_{2},-x_{3})$ and:
$$x\cdot \tilde{x} := x_{0}^{2}-x_{1}^{2}-x_{2}^{2}-x_{3}^{2} $$
For each $m\ge 0$, let $H_{m}$ be the hyperboloid:
$$H_{m}:= \{x\in \mathbb{R}^{4}: \hspace{0.1cm} x\cdot \tilde{x} = m^{2}, x_{0} > 0\}$$

**Question:** I believe $H_{m}$ is a measurable set on $\mathbb{R}^{4}$, but I wasn't able to find a criative way to prove it. Any ideas?

Comment: $H_m$ is the intersection of the closed set defined by $x \cdot \tilde{x} = m^2$ and the open set defined by $x_0 > 0$.

Comment: The function $f : x \mapsto x \cdot \tilde{x}$ is continuous, so $f^{-1}[\{m^2\}]$ is closed.

Comment: @RobArthan in fact! Geometrically, I can see that $x\cdot \tilde{x} = m^{2}$ is closed, but I was trying to find an analitical argument. For instance, the set $\{x \in \mathbb{R}^{4}: x_{0} > 0\}$ is open because the projection $\pi_{0}: (x_{0},x_{1},x_{2},x_{3}) \mapsto x_{0}$ is continuous, so that $\pi_{0}^{-1}((0,\infty))$ is open. But the proof $x\cdot \tilde{x} = m^{2}$ is closed is tricking me, tho.

Comment: Oh, so obvious. I was trying crazy things here. Thanks!